# Javascript: play/pause if clicked and change src

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<audio id="player" src="file.ogg"></audio>
<img id="playpause" src="play.png" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
playpause.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('player').play();
    this.src = 'pause.png';
});
```

Here's what I have so far. I'd like to alternatively play (`document.getElementById('player').play()`) and pause (`document.getElementById('player').pause()`) the song when you click on `#playpause` and also change the `src` when playing (`play.png`) and pausing (`pause.png`).

I can use jQuery but simple Javascript I think is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`paused`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-media-paused) property of the player element.

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');

playpause.addEventListener('click', function () {
    player[player.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
    this.src = (player.paused ? "pause" : "play") + ".png";
});
```

Comment: Much better than adding a flag

Comment: Ok, and to add the change of src?

Comment: Yeah I noticed was fixing :)

Answer (score 3):

How about a flag variable?

```
var playing = false;
playpause.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if(!playing) {
        document.getElementById('player').play();
        this.src = 'pause.png';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('player').pause();
        this.src = 'play.png';
    }
    playing = !playing;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<audio id="player" src="file.ogg" data-state="0"></audio>
<img id="playpause" src="play.png" />
```

**JS**

```
playpause = document.getElementById( 'playpause' );
audio = document.getElementById( 'player' );

playpause.addEventListener('click', function() {
    (player.dataset.state === '0') ? player.play() : player.pause(); player.dataset.state = '1';
});
```

Please note this is untested. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'paused' property of the Audio tag.

```
playpause.addEventListener('click', function () {
 var player = document.getElementById('player');
 if(player.paused){
   player.play();
   this.src = 'pause.png';
 }else{
   player.pause();
   this.src = 'play.png';
 }
});
```